# Use injected metamask inside of an ionic app

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Ive seen this topic mentioned on the ethers of stack exchange before and mostly these questions go unanswered but being that ionic is basically a fancy webview I am wondering if anyone has managed to implemented injected web3 using it

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is import [Web3.JS Library](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) and [Ethereum TX](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx). Metamask is only a graphic interface for some Web3.JS's functions , but you can do everything "manually".

If you develop some **Android** / **iOS** app, you must import **Web3.JS** Library and call **Smart Contracts** from there. **Ethereum TX** will help you creating valid transactions to sign with **Web3.JS**. If someone wants to call a payable function, it's must sign the transaction to do it, so it's must puts its private key in your software.

Some people don't want to share its private keys, so you can create Wallets internally and you manage their private keys.

Comment: Please refrain from mentioning your name on the answer. Thanks :)